# Use Transform Scale onClick

Tags: css, onclick, link-to

I want an image to scale when I click a div element.

I want to click the div which links to another page and scale the image on the second page.

This is how I want the CSS to look:

```
.dragon {
   background-image: url(img/dragon.jpg);
   transform: scale(15);
   transition-duration: 1.7s;
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 1, 0.1);
   transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

Below is the div on the 1st page:

```
<div className="home-littlefinger-img-container">
    <Link to="/dragon" className="littlefinger-img" name="littlefinger"> </Link>
</div>
```

I want the onClick function attached to the link element.

This is the 2nd page:

```
class Dragon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className="dragon-img-container">
          <div className="dragon"></div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dragon;
```

(I only want to use CSS for the scaling.)

Comment: do you want to scale the  image every time you get to the `dragon` page ? not necessary from clicking the link.

Comment: The only way I get to the dragon page is from clicking the link (I want to keep it like that).  But yes every time I get to the dragon page I want it scaled.

Comment: well. your CSS should work every time the page is loaded. If you have included the css somewhere.

Comment: The dragon img container contains the initial size I want the dragon to be (width 70px, height 50px) but it's scaled right away because of the above transform property in the dragon class. If I comment the transform property out it displays the dimensions I want but of course then it doesn't scale..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `animation` not `transition`. That way you can control much better the timing of the 'scaling'

See snippet below :

```css
.dragon {
   background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/70x50');
   height:50px;
   width:70px;
   animation-delay:1s;
   animation-duration:1.7s;
   animation-timing-function:cubic-bezier(1, 0.1, 1, 0.1);
   animation-name: scaleAnimation;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

@keyframes scaleAnimation {
  0% {transform:scale(1);}
  100% {transform:scale(15);}
}
```

```html
<div class="dragon-img-container">
  <div class="dragon"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick and accurate response!! It works!

Comment: Glad i could help ! :D If it solves your problem please don't forget to rate/accept my answer ( green tick :) )\

Comment: Done. Thanks again